# How to find a TFS release in progress?

Tags: powershell, tfs, build, queue, release

I need to fail a build on TFS 2018 if its pipeline is not fully complete. Batching just the build is not enough; the linked release must be finished as well before another build can begin. My idea is to do this in a PowerShell script via the REST API.

I see in the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1#taskstatus) that there's a property called `TaskStatus`. It provides a value of `inProgress`, presumably for releases that are in progress. This might do the trick, but there's no indication of how to actually use it.

Using the REST API, how can I get the `TaskStatus` of a given release?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do this. Can you give some context? A release failing doesn't necessarily mean that the build itself is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in process` and some other values such as `succeeded`, `canceled` just stand for the status of a task in release pipeline.

You could simply use the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/get%20release?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to get a release

`GET https://fabrikam.vsrm.visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=4.1-preview.6`

There should be a value called status:

```
"id": 18,
  "name": "Release-18",
  "status": "abandoned",
  "createdOn": "2017-06-16T01:36:20.397Z",
  "modifiedOn": "2017-06-16T01:36:21.07Z",
  "modifiedBy": {
    "id": "4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227",
    "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
    "uniqueName": "fabfiber@outlook.com",
    "url": "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/A168224e4-29ff-4081-9954-c8780ce81117/_apis/Identities/4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227",
    "imageUrl": "https://fabfiber-inc.visualstudio.com/_api/_common/identityImage?id=4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227"
  },
  "createdBy": {
    "id": "4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227",
    "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
    "uniqueName": "fabfiber@outlook.com",
    "url": "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/A168224e4-29ff-4081-9954-c8780ce81117/_apis/Identities/4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227",
    "imageUrl": "https://fabfiber-inc.visualstudio.com/_api/_common/identityImage?id=4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227"
  },
  "environments": [
    {
      "id": 69,
      "releaseId": 18,
      "name": "Dev",
      "status": "notStarted",
      "variables": {},
      "preDeployApprovals": [],
      "postDeployApprovals": [],
      "preApprovalsSnapshot": {
        "approvals": [
          {
            "rank": 1,
            "isAutomated": false,
            "isNotificationOn": false,
            "approver": {
              "id": "4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227",
              "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
              "uniqueName": "fabfiber@outlook.com",
              "url": "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/A168224e4-29ff-4081-9954-c8780ce81117/_apis/Identities/4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227",
              "imageUrl": "https://fabfiber-inc.visualstudio.com/_api/_common/identityImage?id=4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227"
            },
            "id": 0
          }
```

You could fetch the value status in your return json file, and judge if the release succeed or failed. Finally according to this status to trigger another build or not.

---

**Update**

A sample of the returned json with task's status info:

```
  "deploymentJobs": [
                                {
                                    "job": {
                                        "id": 5,
                                        "timelineRecordId": "855ea6d6-9ed0-442d-b921-0c4add8bb068",
                                        "name": "Release",
                                        "dateStarted": "2018-07-04T08:53:05.9133333Z",
                                        "dateEnded": "2018-07-04T08:53:21.34Z",
                                        "startTime": "2018-07-04T08:53:05.9133333Z",
                                        "finishTime": "2018-07-04T08:53:21.34Z",
                                        "status": "succeeded",
                                        "rank": 1,
                                        "issues": [],
                                        "agentName": "DFA00"
                                    },
                                    "tasks": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 1,
                                            "timelineRecordId": "fa3bb635-eab4-4c1b-9cc0-fdccd7ced33f",
                                            "name": "Initialize Job",
                                            "dateStarted": "2018-07-04T08:53:06.5833333Z",
                                            "dateEnded": "2018-07-04T08:53:06.8033333Z",
                                            "startTime": "2018-07-04T08:53:06.5833333Z",
                                            "finishTime": "2018-07-04T08:53:06.8033333Z",
                                            "status": "succeeded",
                                            "rank": 1,
                                            "issues": [],
                                            "agentName": "DFA00",
                                            "logUrl": "http://xxxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/7658559e-6e61-422a-952b-a5fce0b6ca1d/_apis/Release/releases/49/environments/49/tasks/1/logs?releaseDeployPhaseId=54"
                                        },
```

There should be **timelinerecord**, *starttime*, **finishtime**, **status** for a task deployment result in a single release.

Comment: There are at least three problems with this: 1) The variable name `TaskStatus`, as documented, never appears in any results 2) Specifying `releases/98` (e.g.) always returns ALL releases, not the single one specified 3) Sending the arguments `?api-version=4.1-preview.6` results in a 404 on TFS 2018 (this is not VSTS, as carefully noted in the original question). Documentation appears incorrect and is inadequate in any case. Forward progress using this approach remains blocked.

Comment: @InteXX the value name is just **status** under the task ID. If you got multiple releases, make sure you have entered the project option. The API I was using is something like `GET https://tfsurl/project/_apis/release/16&api-version=4.0` I have add a sample for your reference in my updated reply. Before you are using the API in the code, you could first test it in PostMan.

Comment: *"the value name is just status under the task ID"* This value doesn't indicate the progress of the release under examination. I get an `active` value returned for releases that completed long ago.

Comment: To test your `deploymentJobs` update, I triggered a release that contains only a single PowerShell task whose inline script runs `Start-Sleep -s 60`. During that 60 seconds I ran a pair of REST API commands in my browser to retrieve first the definition in progress, and then from that the release in progress. I received the value pair: `"status":"inProgress"` under the `job` node. So it looks like it works. Thank you. BUT...  I still maintain that the documentation is woefully inadequate (and even inaccurate). If it weren't, we wouldn't have to have this conversation.